# How to group the data in a DataGrid on a certain condition?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

How do I get in the `GridView` to create groups for `State` if he is of `InProgress`, and all other options have been without any group?

```
public class RecordVm: VmBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public State State { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompeleted { get; set; }
    }
    public enum State
    {
        Empty, Opened, InProgress, Completed
    }

     public class MainVm : VmBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<RecordVm> RecordVms { get; } = new ObservableCollection<RecordVm>();

        public ListCollectionView ListCollection {get;}

        public MainVm()
        {
            ListCollection = new ListCollectionView(RecordVms);
            ListCollection.GroupDescriptions?.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("State"));
        }
    }
```

At the moment, I have created a group for each of the variants of State, but such an option does not suit me.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListCollection}"
      Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}"
      RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyleStateGreen}">
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander>
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text=" Items"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>

enter code here
```

Comment: The easiest way might be, you add another Property to your Model and grup by that one, instead trying to skip some groups

Comment: @lokusking, You will not be difficult to make a small example that I better understand your idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, this might group the way you want it to:
Xaml remains Untouched!

**Model**

```
public class RecordVm 
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public State State {
                get { return this._state; }
                set { this._state = value;
                    if (value == State.InProgress)
                        this.InProgress = true;return;
                    this.InProgress = false; }
            }
            private State _state;
            public bool IsCompeleted { get; set; }

            public bool InProgress { get; private set; }


        }
```

**Converter**

```
public class DisplayConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value == null) return "";
                if ((bool) value) return "In Progress";
                return "Finished";
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

**Usage**

```
ListCollection.GroupDescriptions?.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("InProgress", new DisplayConverter()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see if this solves your issue :

```
ListCollection = new ListCollectionView(RecordVms);
ListCollection.GroupDescriptions?.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("State"));
ListCollection.Refresh();

CollectionViewGroup group = (CollectionViewGroup) ListCollection.Groups[0];

ListCollectionView viewOfGroup1 = new ListCollectionView(group.Items);            
viewOfGroup1.Filter = ((i) => { return ((RecordVm)i).State == State.InProgress; });
viewOfGroup1.Refresh();
```